# When should we use permutations when calculating probability? What did I do wrong in this problem?

Tags: statistics

Five men and 5 women are ranked according to their scores on an exami- nation. Assume that no two scores are alike and all 10! possible rankings are equally likely. Let X denote the highest ranking achieved by a woman (for instance, X = 2 if the top-ranked person was male and the next- ranked person was female). Find P{X = i},i = 1,2,3,...,8,9,10.

For example, when X = 5, I understand that we use [(5 choose 4) * 5!] formula since there are 5 possible positions for the 4 lower scoring women, but what about the men? Shouldn't there be a (5 choose 3) * 5! formula for the 3 possible top position and (5 choose 1) for the lowest male position? I'm still trying to piece together why the choose formula applies to the women and not the men in problem when I look at different online answer keys. My attempts are shown below:
[image: My work]

Comment: If you know the set of positions of women's scores, then you also know the set of positions of men's scores.

Comment: So should the numerator be ((5 choose 4) * 5!) * ((5 choose 3) * 5!) *(5 choose 1) * 5!)?

Comment: No.  Once you have chosen the 5 positions for the women (the $i$-th and 4 among the later $10-i$), you do not have to choose the positions for the men.  The numerator should be $\binom{10-i} 4 5! 5!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the situation, label the men and women as $$m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_5, \\ w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_5.$$

Then an ordered $10$-tuple of decreasing ranks might look something like this $$(w_4, w_5, m_1, m_3, w_2, m_4, w_3, m_5, w_1, m_2).$$  In this case, $X = 1$ since the first rank is occupied by $w_4$.

First of all, $\Pr[X > 5] = 0$ since there are only five men.

Next, suppose we wish to count the number of ways that $X = 1$.  To do this, we pick one of the five women to occupy the top rank.  Then there are simply $9!$ ways to pick the rest of the people without any regard to sex, since the lower ranks do not matter.  Each such ordering is unique.  So there are $5(9!)$ such rankings with $X = 1$ out of a total of $10!$, hence $$\Pr[X = 1] = \frac{5(9!)}{10!} = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2},$$ perfectly sensible since there are equally many men as women and one of the two sexes must occupy the top rank.

What about $X = 2$?  This would imply the top rank is occupied by a man, and then the next rank is occupied by a woman.  Now there are $5$ ways to pick a man for the top rank, followed by $5$ ways to pick a woman for the second rank.  The remaining $8$ people can be ordered in any way, so there are $5(5)(8!)$ such orderings and $$\Pr[X = 2] = \frac{5(5)(8!)}{10!} = \frac{5}{18}.$$

For $X = 3$, we apply the same reasoning as above.  There are $5$ ways to choose a man for the top rank, $4$ ways to choose a man for the second rank, and $5$ ways to choose a woman for the third rank.  The remaining people can be ordered in any way.  This gives $$\Pr[X = 3] = \frac{5(4)(5)(7!)}{10!} = \frac{5}{36}.$$

I leave the remaining two cases as an exercise.

In general, if there are $n$ men and $n$ women, what is $\Pr[X = x]$ for each $x \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$?

---

As for where you went wrong, the essential problem is that you are using combinations to enumerate arrangements that are more conveniently described using permutations.  This is because when we look at an elementary outcome, each person is distinguishable, not just whether a man or woman occupies a particular rank.  Note how I wrote a representative outcome above; I did not just write something like
$$(w, w, m, m, w, m, w, m, w, m).$$  This $10$-tuple gives an ordering of men and women, but it doesn't distinguish which men and which women occupied those ranks.  Another way to state this is that such a ranking is ordered by sex but not by person.

But **could** we have solved the problem this way?  After all, each of these $\binom{10}{5} = 252$ rankings by sex should be equiprobable.  Within each of these $252$ rankings by sex, there are $5!$ equally likely orderings of the women and $5!$ equally likely orderings of the men, hence $$\binom{10}{5} (5!)^2 = 10!.$$

The answer is yes.  If we work with these, then for $X = 1$, there is $1$ way to choose $w$ as the first rank, and then there are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to choose the rankings of the $4$ remaining women.  This gives $$\Pr[X = 1] = \frac{1\binom{9}{4}}{\binom{10}{5}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$  For $X = 2$, there is $1$ way to choose $m$ as the first rank, $1$ way to choose $w$ as the second, and then the remaining $4$ women can be placed in the $8$ remaining ranks in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways, hence $$\Pr[X = 2] = \frac{1(1)\binom{8}{4}}{\binom{10}{5}} = \frac{5}{18}.$$  Notice how we are counting *where* the women are placed in the ranks, not *which* women are placed, and this is why we ignore the men, because once we decide, for instance, that the first two ranks are $(m, w, \ldots)$, then if we also decide the remaining $4$ women go in ranks $3, 5, 7, 9$, that forces the men to be in ranks $4, 6, 8, 10$.  When we counted using permutations, we considered both men and women because each person was distinguishable and led to a unique ordering on the particular people.  But if we only distinguish the sex of the person, then we do not need to count the rankings for the men once all of the women are ranked.

Comment: Omg thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about arrangements.   You are not concerned about the identities of the people; only the positions chosen for them.

There are $\binom{10-i}4$ ways to select four among the $10-i$ positions after the $i$-th.

There are $\binom{10}5$ ways to select any five positions among the $10$ .

$$\mathsf P(X=i)~=~\dfrac{\dbinom{10-i}{4}}{\dbinom{10}{5}}~=~\dfrac{(10-i)!~~~5!~5!}{4!~(6-i)!~~~10!}$$